# Get rid of Canvas's Perfect Rectangle

Tags: javascript, canvas

So when you create a rectangle in Canvas. It gives you a perfect rectangle with straight edges.

How do I create a rectangle with rough edges? Or what framework/function should I be looking at? The texture I want for my rectangles is old paper-like https://www.google.com/search?q=old+paper&client=safari&rls=en&biw=1196&bih=799&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMIhP3E4dXQxwIVhqWICh3cPQjC

I apologize if this is a double. I tried searching myself for answer but I don't think I was able to type in the right thing into Google lol

Comment: You can't. You have to draw it point-by-point. You would start with ctx.beginPath(), and then ctx.lineTo() to draw a line. once your shape connects back to the end, use ctx.closePath(), and then you can fill or stroke the shape, the same way you would for any other built-in shape.

Comment: @user2072826 I see. :( Thank you though!

Comment: @Jessica Gu Another option would be to create an image with the correct texture, and use drawImage to display the rectangle.